# How to make the plots for some variables invisible?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using the great [dwplot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dotwhisker/vignettes/dotwhisker-vignette.html) package (which is built on ggplot) to create dot-whisker plots. They look great, but to present my results I'd love to be able to reveal one variable (one row) at a time. So, the first plot has the result invisible for all but Row 1, the second plot has Row 1 and Row 2 visible, etc.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to do that? For example, is there a way to set just a subset of variables to have alpha = 0?

For example, running

```
library(dotwhisker)
dwplot(lm(mpg ~ wt + gear + carb, data = mtcars))
```

gives the following plot.

[image]

I want to create a plot where the 'gear' and 'carb' text appears on the left, but the plots do not appear. I can then sequentially reveal the coefficients and the confidence intervals.

Comment: Thanks - I added more details.

Comment: Are you thinking of an animation style thing such as `gganimate` might produce, or more individual images with each subsequent row revealed - as you might use in a presentation?

Comment: I'm planning to use it in a presentation, so multiple images I think is fine.

Comment: In that case you can subset the data and produce individual plots. You can add `limits` and `breaks` to the `scale_x_discrete` command to retain all the points on the axis.

Comment: Is there a way to do that with dwplot? For example, you can't do dwplot(x) + dwplot(y) and show two plots together like you could with, e.g., geom_point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution where you iterate through predictors (using `for` loop) and pass them to `dwplot`.
This solution first fits the model on all predictors and then passes only a subset of them (following predictors have only `term` identifier, statistics are passed as `NA`)

```
library(dotwhisker)
# Final result
plots <- list()

# Create a model (using tidy to easily subset)
fit <- broom::tidy(lm(mpg ~ wt + gear + cyl, mtcars))

# Iterate through predictors (#1 is intercept)
for(i in 2:nrow(fit)) {
    # empty terms
    if (i < nrow(fit)) {
        # Add following predictors as NA
        terms <- data.frame(term = fit[(i + 1):nrow(fit), ]$term)
    } else {
        terms <- NULL
    }
    plots[[i - 1]] <- dwplot(dplyr::bind_rows(fit[1:i, ], terms)) + 
                          # Add fixed scales that all plots
                          coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-5.5, 1.5))
}

# Final result is stored in list plots
ggpubr::ggarrange(plotlist = plots)
```

[image]